# Kotlin: Alignment.CenterHorizontally does't center text if there is line feed

Tags: kotlin, text, alignment

Here is the Column:

```
Column(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    Text(
        text = Sand().toString(),
        fontSize = 48.sp
    )
}
```

It works fine while text is short. Since line feed appears it stop center the text horizontally.

I tried to add modifier to Text but this doesn't help as well

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

`horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally`

only affects text box but not the text inside this box. You need to use

`textAlign = TextAlign.Center`

to align text inside text box.